# Query for post term that matches user ID

Tags: users, terms

I'm trying to set up something to decide wether the current post has a custom taxonomy term that matches the current users ID.

So far I set up a variable that stores the taxonomy terms of the given post with

```
$terms = get_terms( array(
    'taxonomy' => 'list'
));
```

But now I don't know how to loop through that list of terms in order to match one of the terms names with the user ID. Also, is there a way to do this without running into troubles when for example the user ID is 3 and the post has a term with the name of 30. In this case I do not want this to be a match.

Any guidance is appreciated.

Comment: Your question is not clear enough are you matching term_id = user_id or you have some other ideas?

Comment: No, the name of the Term should correspond with the user id. So all the term names consist of numbers only.

Comment: Do you have the array of users or you have particular id to match?

Comment: I want to check if there is a match for the current users ID

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code it will surely work, before testing this code make sure you have added the categories title as numbers.

```
$terms = get_terms( array(
    'taxonomy' => 'list',
    'hide_empty' => false
));
$user = wp_get_current_user();
if(!empty($terms)){
    foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
        if($term->name == $user->ID){
            // Do something
        }
    }
}
```

This code will works only for post which id you gave.

```
$args = array('orderby' => 'name', 'order' => 'ASC', 'fields' => 'all');
// You need to add Current Post ID here.
$get_terms = wp_get_post_terms($post_id,'list',$args);

//Get Current User Info
$user = wp_get_current_user();

//Check array is not empty
if(!empty($get_terms)){
    foreach ( $get_terms as $term ) {
        if($term->name == $user->ID){
            // Do something
        }
    }
}
```